# Ajuda com PDO (PREPARE)

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo, crud, prepared-statement

Olá. Estou tentando fazer um CRUD usando PHP OO.

Mas quando executo me apresenta erro no prepare da classe PDO.

Tenho somente por enquanto o código de cadastro no banco e o código de conexao ao banco:

Banco.php

```
<?php

class Banco{

private $host = 'localhost', $usuario = 'root', $senha = '', $nomeBanco = 'rbtech', $conexao = null;

public function __construct(){
    $this->conecta();   // Chama metodo para conexao
}   //  Fim construct

public function __destruct() {
    if($this->conexao != null){
        $this->conexao = null;
    }   //  Fim destruct
}

    public function conecta(){
        try{
            $this->conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->nomeBanco, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die('Erro ao conectar com o banco' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }   //  Fim conecta
}
```

Cadastrar.php

```
<?php

require_once '../Lib/Banco.php';

class Cadastro extends Banco{

// Porpriedades
public $nome, $sobrenome, $idade;

public function cadastrar(){
    if($_POST){ //  Verifica se é POST
        $pdo = parent::__construct();   //  Chama o construtor da classe Banco
        $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (nome, sobrenome, idade) VALUES(:nome, :sobrenome, :idade)";   // Query INSERT
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
        $stmt->bindParam(':sobrenome', $sobrenome);
        $stmt->bindParam(':idade', $idade);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            header('Location: ../index.php');
        }else{
            echo 'Erro ao cadastrar. ';
            print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
        }
    }
}   //  Fim cadastrar
}

$cad = new Cadastro();
$cad->nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cad->sobrenome = $_POST['sobre'];
$cad->idade = $_POST['idade'];
$cad->cadastrar();
var_dump($cad);
```

Estou iniciando meus estudos em Orientação a objetos com PHP, então esta maneira de receber os dados do formulário com orientação a objetos talvez não seja a melhor maneira de fazer, mas um iniciante nos estudos como eu, foi o que consegui desenvolver. E como disse, o código quando executado acusa erro no prepare...

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Alguém poderia me ajudar com este problema?

E aceito sugestões de como receber melhor os dados de um formulário com orientação a objetos.

Grato!

Comment: Acho que o problema pode estar no html..

Comment: Aqui esta meu HTML http://pastebin.com/5G1x2AWL

Comment: Revi e não consegui achar algum erro nele

Comment: Construtor não retorna valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu exemplo na sua classe Banco você precisa da um return no construtor onde vc chama o methodo $this->conecta() e tambem um return na variavel $this->conecta() onde vc faz conexão com o banco, eu fiz as alterações onde precisa:

```
private $host = 'localhost', $usuario = 'root', $senha = '', $nomeBanco = 'rbtech', $conexao = null;

public function __construct(){
    return $this->conecta();   // Chama metodo para conexao
}   //  Fim construct

public function __destruct() {
    if($this->conexao != null){
        $this->conexao = null;
    }   //  Fim destruct
}

public function conecta(){
    try{
        return $this->conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->nomeBanco, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Erro ao conectar com o banco' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}   //  Fim conecta
```

Edite também as variáveis que vc esta alimentando o bindParam, esta assim:

```
 $stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
 $stmt->bindParam(':sobrenome', $sobrenome);
 $stmt->bindParam(':idade', $idade);
```

Mas deve editar para:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':nome', $this->nome);
$stmt->bindParam(':sobrenome', $this->sobrenome);
$stmt->bindParam(':idade', $this->idade);
```

Pois você esta alimentando essas variáveis fora do methodo.

Comment: Obrigado Robson, o erro no prepare foi resolvido. Mas agora o código esta dando erro quando faz a verificação no execute(). Ele retorna false, e a mensagem que o errorInfo() traz é a de que o campo nome não pode ser nulo, mas quando dou var_dump($cad), no objeto, a variável nome esta preenchida. Tenho quase certeza que isso se deve a eu estar instanciando a classe de maneira errada, sabe me dizer se seria isso mesmo? Poderia me ajudar? Não consegui resolver :/     |     Grato!

Comment: Putz cara, era isso mesmo, agora esta tudo ok. Ainda me acostumo a acessar atributos assim kkk